# How to show convex hull of finitely many vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k$ is any finite set of vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$. A convex combination of these vectors is $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_ix_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i=1$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_k\geq 0$.
The set $C$ which contains all the convex combinations is called convex hull.

Show that $C$ is compact in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I know that since the underlying space is $\mathbb{R^n}$, using Heine-Borel theorem we need to show the boundedness and closedness. For the boundedness if I assume the  2-norm of $x_i$'s is bounded, i.e., $\|x_i\| \leq \|M\|$ then

$$
x=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_ix_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \|M\|=\|M\|
$$

But for the closedness we need a sequence $(x_k)$ in $C$ and show this converges in $C$. How to show this part?

Comment: You don't need to *assume* the two norm is bounded.  You have a finite set of vectors, each with finite length.  Just take the maximum of the lengths.

Comment: For closed, just show the complement is open.